# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm doing some kafka Streams aggregation and writing aggregated records to the topic and getting the following errors. I'm using custom json serde for the aggregation helper class. The solution I found on some blogs to this problem is to increase the max.request.size.

Though I increase the max.request size to from default to 401391899, the serialized aggregation message size keeps increasing on the subsequent writes to the topic.

Running the streams after 10 mins, the below error shows up. Not sure if the problem is with my serde or should I change any config settings other than max.request.size to overcome this problem.

Message written to topic;

```
{A=5, B=1, C=0, D=87, E=1, F=0.4482758620689655 }   
{A=6, B=1, C=0, D=87, E=1, F=0.4482758620689655 }  
{A=7, B=1, C=2, D=87, E=1, F=0.4482758620689655 }
```

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 2292506 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.

```
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:1043)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:784)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInArray(JsonReader.java:693)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:376)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:349)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
    at com.data.agg.streams.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:34)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.maybeForward(CachingWindowStore.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.access$200(CachingWindowStore.java:34)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:131)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.evict(NamedCache.java:222)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.maybeEvict(ThreadCache.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.put(ThreadCache.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.put(CachingWindowStore.java:149)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamWindowAggregate$KStreamWindowAggregateProcessor.process(KStreamWindowAggregate.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:180)
[Thread-2] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - Stopped Kafka Stream process
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your code, not just the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shot into the darkness, as you did not share you code, but I assume that you assemble records within your window-aggregation into a larger and larger record that you maintain as aggregation result.

Because state is backed by a Kafka topic for fault-tolerance, Streams writes a record into this topic (one record per key, with the value being the state that belong to the key). As you state (per key) grows over time, the "state records" grow over time, and eventually exceed the max-size bound.

Comment: I have a use case where I need to do a distinct count on the useragent strings by ip. At times, as some ips get more than 50000 unique useragents, its tough to fit these records in memory and do a ktable aggregation.

 As these records grow over time and producing the below error org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException The message is 947859917 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.

Comment: For distinct counts the original values needs to be retained in a hashset  per record for unique count.

How to handle such records that exceed max-size bound. I believe this is the reason I'm gettting the record too large exception.

Comment: You can only change the configuration (see http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#non-streams-configuration-parameters) or change you code to not produce records with increase size.

Comment: I agree to your point that I have to go with the configuration change.However, I was not sure whether increasing the message size would decrease the throughput. As an alternate, I did hash the unique useragent string for distinct count, That reduced the record size and solved my problem.